# How do I add a product key running a remote script to install software using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, remote-server

I need to be able to run the script below remotely and add a product key. The script works but just halts because a popup dialog box comes up and I can't figure out how to add the product key. I've searched Google for many different queries and all I was able to find is how to change a product key for software already installed. I know the script works and connects to the server by using the first code string below. The second code string is the code I am using to connect to the server and run the script. How do I apply a product code in the installation script so it will apply remotely when the script runs. It is my understanding that /silent runs the install without the need to add a product code. Is this accurate or is there some other way to need to go about to accomplish this?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName devapppackage -ScriptBlock {1}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName anycomputername -ScriptBlock { c:\Temp\anysoftware.msi /silent }
```

Comment: Please read the help for [MSIEXEC.EXE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec) to learn how to install an MSI package ... read it completely including the examples!!

Comment: @Olaf, unless I am missing something, this is only about command line and command line does not work in PowerShell, or at least I'm not advanced enough to understand how to make it work. The switches I get and understand that part. Please clarify how command line can be used to execute a remote PowerShell script.

Comment: Actually I did not get what you mean with "apply a product code". I thought you want  to install an MSI package on a remote server. If that's the case you should carefully read the help topic I linked for you. The MSI file has to be on the remote server and the command line should be something like `msiexec.exe /i c:\Temp\anysoftware.msi /qn`.

Comment: @Olaf I guess you are still not understanding. NOT COMMAND LINE, but POWERSHELL. If you are saying that the command line can be used in PowerShell, please propose an answer demonstrating how to do that using POWERSHELL. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You already have the PowerShell command line in your question!?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an `MST` file, a MSI Transform file.  There a lot of tools to do this.  When you do it, you'll have the option to make the installer totally silent and automatically bundle the product key into the installer.

Some MSIs do support a flag to add a product key, but not all of them.  So, making an MST is the standard way to go.

This is referred to as 'Application Packaging', when you make a silent installer and bundle in the properties needed.  Its a great skill to have on your resume.

You could use Orca to do this, or do it by hand, but that's actually really hard.  Instead, use the industry standard tool, AdminStudio.

[Here's a good guide on how to do it.](https://www.windowsmanagementexperts.com/application-deployment-adminstudio-tuner/application-deployment-adminstudio-tuner.htm)

If this is for work, you should download the AdminStudio trial, then follow that guide and give it a whirl.

Packaging MSI's by hand is time consuming and not really a relevant skill to learn these days, so that's my recommendation, as someone who did packing as part of my job for years.

Comment: this seems most useful. I will spend some time on this as we will be doing more with PowerShell for remote installs and getting away from using task sequences.

Comment: FoxDeploy, can you provide any online documentation or direction as to how to deploy a package remotely using PowerShell? We use SCCM and the package will be available in SCCM, however, we do not want to allow access to a particular server by individuals so we want them to be able to deploy the package and install the program remotely using PowerShell.

Comment: In SCCM 2012 and up, there is a concept of a Content Library which is accessible to the SCCM Client, that uses a special credential, but not just freely browsable by random users.  I think what you're concerned about isn't really a thing any more.